# Garbage value in Boost::Array using with Boost::Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, boost, boost-asio

**Client** is *writing* like this

```
    std::string line;
    std::cin>>line;      
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(line));
```

**Server** is *Reading* like this

```
void reader(){   
           socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf),
           boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read,shared_from_this()));     
  }
void handle_read()
    {
          std::cout.write(buf.data(),1024);
          std::cout<<"\n";
    }
  tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::array<char, 1024> buf;
```

Now when i am writing a line "hello how are you" from client , it is just printing "hello" and then garbage values
here is the output which server is showing:

```
helloA0�B��B�����a�Pa�!0�B�b����uB�`�#K|BP�b��D4B���Bb�Pa���e��e�����pc�!0�Be���xB�`�#KcBe�:7B�����e��e���
```

how can I remove this garbage values and get complete message/line from client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `operator >>` uses whitespace as delimiter like `scanf()`. You should use `std::getline()`.

   ```
   std::getline(std::cin, line);
   ```
2. Why do you use `cout.write()`? just use `operator <<`.

   ```
   std::cout << buf.data();
   ```

   Of course, you should care `'\0'`-terminate. Probably boost.asio gives the size of received bytes to your handler.

Comment: And the garbage shows up because of 2. You write 1024 bytes, which is far more than your message.

Comment: @tsv.dimitrov that's why he should care `'\0'`.

Comment: I think std::cout.write() will always write count (2nd parameter) number of bytes, no matter if there is \0 or not.

Comment: @tsv.dimitrov so I said OP should use `operator <<`, don't I?

Comment: you did but this doesn't explain the garbage in the output, right?

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems:

First of all, you write `1024` bytes from the buffer, no matter how much data you actually read.

Secondly, TCP connections are *streaming*, which means there is no message boundaries, and that leads to the possibility that a single receive call can get less than what was sent, and you need multiple receives to receive a complete message.

Thirdly, and which is answered by others, the input operator doesn't work as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

[`>>` just reads up to the first delimiter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt), that is a space in your case.

Your other problem is that you don't tell your receiver how long your message is going to be.